# Laravel artisan terminal console, how and where can i instantiate it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4. I have installed the latest version using git. i have installed the composer.how and where can i instantiate artisan terminal console in Laravel?

Comment: just go to your project folder and run `php artisan` you should see list of artisan available commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a new Laravel instance using git, but use the composer command found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#installation).

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject
```

This command will create a clean Laravel installation and install all dependencies for you.